# How to get XML data: SenderNumber and TextDecoded from each node in C#

Tags: c#, xml, wpf

So I have .xml file generated by network device. This .xml is looking like that :

```
<xml>
<messages>
  <item>
   <UpdatedInDB>   2019-01-14 15:25:05  <  /UpdatedInDB>
   <ReceivingDateTime>2018-10-22 09:53:51</ReceivingDateTime>
   <Text>004B0075006C0074007500720061</Text>
   <SenderNumber>+420000000000</SenderNumber>
   <Coding>Default_No_Compression</Coding>
   <UDH/>
   <SMSCNumber>+420000000000</SMSCNumber>
   <Class>-1</Class>
   <TextDecoded>Kultura</TextDecoded>
   <ID>29</ID>
   <RecipientID></RecipientID>
   <Processed>t</Processed>
   <id_folder>1</id_folder>
   <readed>true</readed>
   <oid/>
   <Status>0</Status>
  </item>
  <item>
   <UpdatedInDB>   2019-01-14 15:25:05  <  /UpdatedInDB>
   <ReceivingDateTime>2018-10-22 09:53:51</ReceivingDateTime>
   <Text>004B0075006C0074007500720061</Text>
   <SenderNumber>+420000000000</SenderNumber>
   <Coding>Default_No_Compression</Coding>
   <UDH/>
   <SMSCNumber>+420000000000</SMSCNumber>
   <Class>-1</Class>
   <TextDecoded>Kultura</TextDecoded>
   <ID>29</ID>
   <RecipientID></RecipientID>
   <Processed>t</Processed>
   <id_folder>1</id_folder>
   <readed>true</readed>
   <oid/>
   <Status>0</Status>
  </item>
</message>
</xml>
```

How do I get SenderNumber and textDecoded from each node?

I managed to get data only from first node using this

```
{
        string baseUrl = "http://192.168.253.160/index.php/http_api/read_sms";
        WebClient client = new WebClient();

        client.QueryString.Add("login", "admin");
        client.QueryString.Add("pass", "password");
        client.QueryString.Add("folder", "inbox");
        client.QueryString.Add("responsetype", "xml");
        client.QueryString.Add("unread", "1");
        /*client.QueryString.Add("to", cislo);
          client.QueryString.Add("message", text);*/

        client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0");
        Stream receivedStream = client.OpenRead(baseUrl);
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(receivedStream);
        string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
        receivedStream.Close();
        reader.Close();

        //parsing

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

        doc.LoadXml(result);

        string cislo = "0";
        string zprava = "0";

        XmlNodeList number = doc.GetElementsByTagName("SenderNumber");
        for (int i = 0; i < number.Count; i++)
        {
            cislo = number[i].InnerXml;
        }

        XmlNodeList text = doc.GetElementsByTagName("TextDecoded");
        for (int i = 0; i < text.Count; i++)
        {
            zprava = text[i].InnerXml;
        }

        MessageBox.Show(cislo);
        MessageBox.Show(zprava);
    }
```

The problem is that I read only unread messages from api. If I read only the first node I will lose the rest and will not be there for the second time because they will be 'read' already.

Anyone who can give me a advice for this? I was trying to google but didn't really find anything what would work for me.

Thank you very much.

Comment: You have loaded a complete `XmlDocument doc`. Where do you "read only the first node" and loose something exactly?

Comment: _XmlNodeList number = doc.GetElementsByTagName("SenderNumber");
        for (int i = 0; i < number.Count; i++)
        {
            cislo = number[i].InnerXml;
        }_ 
This part of code shouldn't go through all elements and get listed one? "senderNumber?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside of your `for` loops, you always replace the value of your variables (`cislo` or `zprava`), so in the end you're only going to see the last values parsed. If you want to keep track of them all, either store them in a list or array, or append them directly to the string. For example,

```
var cislo = new List<string>();
var zprava = new List<string>();

XmlNodeList number = doc.GetElementsByTagName("SenderNumber");
for (int i = 0; i < number.Count; i++)
{
    cislo.Add(number[i].InnerXml);
}

XmlNodeList text = doc.GetElementsByTagName("TextDecoded");
for (int i = 0; i < text.Count; i++)
{
    zprava.Add(text[i].InnerXml);
}

MessageBox.Show(string.Join(", ", cislo));
MessageBox.Show(string.Join(", ", zprava));
```

Comment: @Cabry By the way, if my answer was useful, you can click on the "up arrow" next to my answer. In a way, `SenderNumber` and `TextDecoded` are "tied up" by the fact that they have the same index number in the lists. For example, both `cislo[0]` and `zprava[0]` refer to the first `SenderNumber` and `TextDecoded`, respectively.

Comment: Oh yea, sure I forgot.. Thank you very much it was helpfull. I appreciated that man. I still need to learn so much in programming :) ty

Answer (score 0):

You can use [XElement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xelement) to fetch data and pack it into [anonymous type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types):

```
var xml = XElement.Parse(result);
var data = xml
           .Elements()
           .Select(e => new { SenderNumber = e.Element("SenderNumber").Value,
                              TextDecoded = e.Element("TextDecoded").Value });
// iterate over collection
data.ToList().ForEach(e => Console.WriteLine($"Sender: {e.SenderNumber}, " +
                                             $"TextDecoded: {e.TextDecoded}"));
```